# Google Sheet Delete a Row Every time value of Column Disappear With Appscript

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a table like this in **Sheet1**

[image]

Sheet2 is a query function from sheet1 where Status='Done'. And sheets 2 got a column is dropdown selection, got 2 value to choose (1 or 2)

[image]

Every time, if i changed the value from of **status** column in Sheet1. For example:

[image]

The data in Sheet 2 will change like this

[image]

But I want the Sheet2 becomes:

[image]

Every time the value of **Name** column in sheet 2 disappear, it will automate delete all row of that observe.

I have try with on edit function, but it not work for my case. So I willing to listen from all your help.